# Linux Apline: restart nginx

Tags: nginx, alpine-linux

I have Alpine Linux, 3.15.0 version on the server.
The installed nginx version is 1.21.6. I have performed `apk update`

`nginx -t` command successfully responds with

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I type `nginx -s reload` server responds with

```
2023/02/03 10:58:00 [notice] 54#54: signal process started
```

but nothing actually happens. It's like the process started and that's all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Reload and restart are not the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525465/when-to-restart-and-not-reload-nginx

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control), command `nginx -s reload` actually sends signal to nginx master process and

> once the master process receives the signal to reload configuration,
> it checks the syntax validity of the new configuration file and tries
> to apply the configuration provided in it. If this is a success, the
> master process starts new worker processes and sends messages to old
> worker processes, requesting them to shut down.

Thus, we can consider that nginx is restarted (If we disregard the fact that the master process itself continued to work).

At the same time, if you want to totally restart nginx, you can stop it with `nginx -s quit` command and then start again. Or that's much better use your system service manager. If I'm not mistaken, there is an open-rc in Alpine, thus command will be `rc-service nginx restart`.